# Can I use MJS instead of CJS as Rollup Config

Tags: rollup

My Rollup project is like this...

```
// rollup.config.js
import pkg from "./package.json";
import {getRollupServerConfig} from "@jrg/build/dist/index.cjs";
const config = getRollupServerConfig(pkg);
export { config as default };
```

But when I try to make it mjs

```
// main: @jrg/build/dist/index.mjs
import {getRollupServerConfig} from "@jrg/build";
```

It fails because of...

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';                                                                 ^^^^^^^
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I assume this is because rollup is expecting CJS. Is it possible?

Comment: It will look for mjs and js extensions

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can I do it like this....

```
// package.json
...
"scripts":{
  "build":"node --experimental-json-modules ./node_modules/.bin/rollup --config rollup.config.mjs"
},
```

[More Examples](https://github.com/jrgleason/jrg-material)